# how to replace all quotes ' " in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to remove simple ' and double quotes " with bash command, but I can't remove ' with bash command.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong but this command gives me an error, anyone have any idea?

```
user_download_dir_folder=$(echo ${user_download_dir_folder} | sed "s/\"\'//g")
```

Comment: You're replacing `"` followed by `'`, not replacing them separately.

Comment: Remember to quote your variables. Otherwise multiple spaces will be collapsed.

Comment: `sed` is the wrong tool for removing single characters.  Use `tr -d '"'"'"` or `tr -d "\"'"`

Comment: Or just `tr -d \"\'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem with `sed "s/\"\'//g"` is that you're trying to match a `"` followed by a `'`. You should put them in **bracket expression** or match either of the quotes.

Let's say this is your input:

```sh
user_download_dir_folder="abc\"1'23'foo\"bla"

echo "$user_download_dir_folder"

abc"1'23'foo"bla
```

You may use `sed` as this:

```sh
sed "s/[\"']//g" <<< "$user_download_dir_folder"

abc123foobla
```

Or in bash:

```sh
echo "${user_download_dir_folder//[\'\"]/}"

abc123foobla
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it's working.
finally i did this
  

    
  user_download_dir_folder=$(echo ${user_download_dir_folder} | sed "s/\"//g" | sed "s/'//g") #remove ' and " 

but your solution is much better, and this solution is more elegant, and I didn't even think of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [string](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) [manipulation](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) or [`tr`](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/tr1.html):

```sh
user_download_dir_folder=$(tr -d \"\' <<< "$user_download_dir_folder")
# OR
user_download_dir_folder="${user_download_dir_folder//[\"\']/}"
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/4sfOTz):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
user_download_dir_folder="12\"4'5"
user_download_dir_folder=$(tr -d \"\' <<< "$user_download_dir_folder")
echo "$user_download_dir_folder"
## => 1245

user_download_dir_folder="12\"4'5"
user_download_dir_folder="${user_download_dir_folder//[\"\']/}"
echo "$user_download_dir_folder"
## => 1245
```

Comment: ...alternatives include [BashFAQ #100](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100), [BashFAQ #73](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073), and [the bash-hackers' page on parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Added to my list of "best Bash links" :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot, it's working. finally i did this

```
user_download_dir_folder=$(echo ${user_download_dir_folder} | sed "s/\"//g" | sed "s/'//g") #remove ' and "
```

but your solution is much better, and this solution is more elegant, and I didn't even think of it.